# Not Serializable exception when reading Kafka records with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

When streaming from Kafka using Spark 2.0, I am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: 
Task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) had a not serializable result: 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: 
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(
topic = mytopic, partition = 0, offset = 422337, 
CreateTime = 1472871209063, checksum = 2826679694, 
serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 95874, 
key = null, value = <JSON GOES HERE...>
```

Here are the relevant portion of the code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val topics = Array("ecfs")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

stream
  .map(_.value())
  .flatMap(message =>  {
    // parsing here...
  })
  .foreachRDD(rdd => {
    // processing here...
  })

ssc.start()
```

From what I can tell, it is this line that's causing the problem `.map(_.value())`, how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use .map on Dstream:[String,String] like you used there. I think you can use transform and then apply map as follows

`val streamed_rdd_final = streamed_rdd.transform{ rdd => rdd.map(x => x.split("\t")).map(x=>Array(check_time_to_send.toString,check_time_to_send_utc.toString,x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),x(5))).map(x => x(1)+"\t"+x(2)+"\t"+x(3)+"\t"+x(4)+"\t"+x(5)+"\t"+x(6)+"\t"+x(7)+"\t")}`

or you can use .map as you used but rather doing _.value() you should try sending a function into the map, like I did below

```
stream.map{case (x, y) => (y.toString)}
```